# SVN selective commit

Tags: svn, commit

Is there a way to do a selective commit from command-line?

I would like to commit some, but not all of the modified files. I'm thinking in the lines of parsing the output of `svn status`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put the files you're working on in a [changelist](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.changelists.html):

> Subversion's changelist support allows
>   you to create changelists by applying
>   labels to files you want to be
>   associated with that changelist,
>   remove those labels, and limit the
>   scope of the files on which its
>   subcommands operate to only those
>   bearing a particular label.

This way, you can go about your work, and when you type SVN commands (e.g. `svn diff, svn st, svn ci`, etc.), you can specify a changelist and only those files in the changelist will be worked on.

Comment: Too bad svn pre-1.5 does not seem to have this 'changelist' feature. Having used git, it feels like a real pain in the neck to use svn commit

Comment: I suppose . . . for all those people using 4-year old SVN that is now two generations out of date . . . (will become 3 generations out of date in the next month or so)

Answer (score 13):

```
svn commit -m 'Fixed bug 1234' file1.c file2.c directory/*.h
```

Comment: This is handy if there's a few files. And you can't use tab completion on the removed files.

Comment: This one won't work when you do `directory/*` but `directory` contains unversioned files.

Answer (score 0):

```
svn commit file1 file2 -m "Message"
```

Use that

Answer (score 0):

I have homemade recipe for this...

```
svn commit `cat change_list.txt` -m "Message"
```

The **` `** (as know as well as back-quotes) that serves to executes an "internal" command (inside other command).

**chance_list.txt** is a file that contains in each a line a path to a file you want to commit.

For example, it contains the following text:

```
project/A.java
project/B.java
```

Instead of using the commit command specifying one by one the files, let the operating system do the "listing" for you by concatenating the list of files to the command using the above syntax.

So that way you could simply do the work and everybody is happy :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: also very useful for svn diff `cat change_list.txt`